# how to change HTML value in UITextView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have description option in database and convert this into `JSON` format. After fetching from database i'm displaying into `UITextView`. But it's showing below values.

```
<p>table : 1</p><p>table : 2</p><div><p>table : 3</p><div><p>table : 4</p><div><p>table : 5</p><div><p>table : 6</p><p>table : 7</p><p>table : 8</p><div>&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div>
```

HTML decode:

```
NSString *decodeString = [self htmlEntityDecode:productDescription];
txtt.text = decodeString;
```

Comment: <div> tag is not supported in textview

Answer (score 0):

Remove all html tag from html string

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location !=    NSNotFound)
   s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) is a library that converts html string to plain string.

Install it via CocoaPods and simply import `#import <MWFeedParser/NSString+HTML.h>` to your project, and convert your HTML String to plain by this code:

```
NSString *yourHTMLString;
NSString *plainText = [yourHTMLString stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```

I use this for almost all kind of HTML symbols that get formatted as code in HTML, which are not readable.

Hope it helps, and give me feedback! :)